# Worst-Fit Memory Allocation

Tags: c, pointers, memory, heap-memory, allocation

I wanted to make a heap that uses the worst fit algorithm to allocate the memory. Currently, I have a heap that uses the first-fit algorithm, which is not what I wanted. How do I make it so that it does the worst fit instead and what do I need to change so that it finds the block with the biggest differences?
Here's The code:

```
    struct Block
    {
       int block_size; 
       struct Block *next_block; 
       void *data;
    };
    const int void_size = sizeof(void*);
    const int overhead = sizeof(int) + void_size;
    Block *free_head;
    void* my_alloc(int size)
    {
       int frag = 0;
       if (size % void_size != 0)
           frag = 4 - size % void_size;
       size += frag;
       Block *temp = free_head;
       Block* prev = temp;
       while (temp)
       {
           if (temp->block_size >= size)
           {
               printf("Free Head Block Size:%i\n", free_head->block_size);
               if (free_head->block_size >= size + overhead)
               {
                   printf("Split and Head\n");
                   Block *b = (Block*)((unsigned char*)free_head + size + overhead);
                   b->block_size = free_head->block_size - size - overhead;
                   b->data = (Block*)((unsigned char*)b + overhead);
                   b->next_block = free_head->next_block;
                   free_head->block_size = size;
                   free_head->next_block = NULL;
                   free_head = b;
                   return &temp->data;
               }
               else if (temp->block_size >= size + overhead)
               {
                   printf("Split and Not Head\n");
                   Block *b = (Block*)((unsigned char*)temp + size + overhead);
                   b->block_size = temp->block_size - size - overhead;
                   b->data = (Block*)((unsigned char*)b + overhead);
                   b->next_block = temp->next_block;
                   prev->next_block = b;
                   temp->next_block = NULL;
                   temp->block_size = size;
                   return &temp->data;
               }
               else if (free_head->block_size < size + overhead) 
               {
                   printf("No Split and Head\n");
                   free_head = free_head->next_block;
                   temp->next_block = NULL;
                   return &temp->data;
               }
               else 
               {
                   printf("No Split and Not Head\n");
                   temp = temp->next_block;
                   prev->next_block = NULL;
                   return &prev->data;
               }
           }
           else
           {
               Block* prev = temp;
               temp = temp->next_block;
           }
       }
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure you always grab the biggest chunk on the free list unless it isn't big enough.  If it isn't big enough, then you allocate more space from the system.

Comment: What is your problem with finding the worst fitting block? Are you unclear about how to compare two blocks for how bad they fit? Are you unclear how to search through all available blocks? Are you unclear about how to keep track of the worst? All the rest of possible problems I think we can exclude, because you would also have them with first fit. I mean you are not simply asking to be given the code for worst fit, are you? You have implemented the shown first fit, didn't you? And you want to learn to implement the worst fit, don't you? So you should explain about the problem you encountered.